# Error "Your requirements.txt is invalid" when following tutorial AWS Elastic Beanstalk's Flask tutorial

Tags: python, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I'm following AWS Elastic Beanstalk's [Flask tutorial](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/create-deploy-python-flask.html) to deploy the sample application.

Though I get error **Your requirements.txt is invalid** - in full as below. I [google](https://www.google.com.vn/?ion=1&espv=2#newwindow=1&q=%22AWS%20Elastic%20Beanstalk%22%20%2B%20flask%20%2B%20tutorial%20%2B%20error%20%2B%20%22Your%20requirements.txt%20is%20invalid%22) for this error though I get no helpful solution for me.

My **requirements.txt** file is pasted in below sections. And I'm using *Ubuntu Desktop 16.04*

As you may succeed the deployment following the tutorial, please share. Thank you.

## Error

```
ERROR: Your requirements.txt is invalid. Snapshot your logs for details.
ERROR: [Instance: i-c78c8f57] Command failed on instance. Return code: 1 Output: (TRUNCATED)...)
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 540, in check_call
    raise CalledProcessError(retcode, cmd)
  CalledProcessError:
    Command
    '/opt/python/run/venv/bin/pip install -r /opt/python/ondeck/app/requirements.txt'
    returned non-zero exit status 1.
  Hook /opt/elasticbeanstalk/hooks/appdeploy/pre/03deploy.py failed.
  For more detail, check /var/log/eb-activity.log using console or EB CLI.

INFO: Command execution completed on all instances. Summary: [Successful: 0, Failed: 1].
WARN: Environment health has transitioned from Pending to Degraded. Command failed on all instances. Initialization completed 45 seconds ago and took 3 minutes.
ERROR: Create environment operation is complete, but with errors. For more information, see troubleshooting documentation.
```

## requirements.txt

```
click==6.6
Flask==0.11.1
itsdangerous==0.24
Jinja2==2.8
MarkupSafe==0.23
pkg-resources==0.0.0
Werkzeug==0.11.10
```

Answer (score 3):

I tested locally and was able to replicate your problem. To get more information about what went wrong on instance I used `eb logs` to view the logs currently on the EC2 instances. From that I was able to see the full stack in the `eb-activity.log`

```
 Collecting pkg-resources==0.0.0 (from -r /opt/python/ondeck/app/requirements.txt (line 4))
    Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement pkg-resources==0.0.0 (from -r /opt/python/ondeck/app/requirements.txt (line 4)) (from versions: )
  No matching distribution found for pkg-resources==0.0.0 (from -r /opt/python/ondeck/app/requirements.txt (line 4))
```

I'm not sure where the `pkg-resources=0.0.0` came from but it's not a valid package in pip. I was able to delete that line and deploy successfully.

You may want to verify the output of your `pip freeze` and see if that library is actually there.

Comment: Thanks. I'll try that again and back to us later

Comment: By the way I dont write the requirement file myself. I generate it via pip freeze command.