# Memory Error when installing torch from requirements.txt

Tags: python, django, amazon-web-services, memory, torch

I am trying to deploy my Django app on AWS. It works fine locally, and it works fine when I remove the torch from requirements.txt and comment out the code that depends on it. However, when trying to deploy the full app, I run into a memory error trying to install torch. [Here](https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1D84dvyHXZlqMxzm4Sa1IXgjFeaAW8n8R?usp=sharing) is a link to my requirements.txt file and the eb logs. I thought upgrading from a T2.micro instance to a T2.small instance would do the trick, but it did not. Anyone have advice where I should go from here?

Comment: Can you post the actual error? Most likely you just need to go up again in instance sizes. a t2.small is still less RAM than an average smartphone.

Comment: You can also use `ps` or `top` to figure out how much memory the app requires, and pick an instance type based on that (with some extra space for OS and application heap).

Comment: There's no `MemoryError` in your EB logs but there is this: `ERROR Your requirements.txt is invalid. Snapshot your logs for details.` Try [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18554666/invalid-requirements-txt-on-deploying-django-app-to-aws-beanstalk) & [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38893004/error-your-requirements-txt-is-invalid-when-following-tutorial-aws-elastic-bea). Also, your logs show Python 2.7 being used? Is that intentional?

Answer (score 3):

"MemoryError" usually indicates that you don't have enough RAM. Either upgrade your memory, or try installing PyTorch (or `requirements.txt`) with `--no-cache-dir` argument like this:

```
pip --no-cache-dir install ...
```